# How to add title for selected value in md-select?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am having md-select like :

```
    <md-select ng-model="someModel" title={{someModel}}>
<md-option ng-value="opt.id" ng-repeat="opt in neighborhoods2">{{ opt.name }}</md-option>
```

It shows opt.id value in title.But I have to show opt.name in title.How to add a title attribute for the selected value's name?

Comment: Is `opt.id` sequential? Can you use it as an index in `neighborhoods2`?

Answer (score 0):

```
for that you have to select object in ng-value like 

     <md-select ng-model="someModel" title={{someModel.name}}>
    <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in neighborhoods2">{{ opt.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>

but make sure in your controller you will get an object so you have to get id as

if(angular.isString(someModel)){
     var myValue= JSON.parse(someModel).id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the value to `opt.name`, you could use the `opt` object itself as the value. That way, your `md-select` model will have the name and id of whatever item is selected.

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/standard/pen/JKKeEy